# How can I send data array from laravel blade to vue component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.3, vue-component

If I do `{{ dd($message_data ) }}` on the laravel blade, the result like this :

[image]

I want to send the array data to vue component

On laravel view blade, I try like this :

```
<message-list :message-data="{{ $message_data }}"></message-list>
```

My message list vue component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
       ...
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['messageData'],
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.messageData)
            console.log('test')
        }
    }
</script>
```

The result of console.log not display

And the result like this :

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

If I try like this :

```
<message-list message-data="test"></message-list>
```

The result of console.log show. But it is array not show

Comment: I'd recommend just having an API endpoint in your `/api` subdirectory and using it to pull the information from the database, but that may just be me.

Comment: try to get paginator's underlying collection by `getCollection` method

Comment: The LengthAwarePaginator implements the Jsonable class, so you should just be able to json encode that `{{ json_encode($message_data) }}`

Comment: craig's comment is the solution here. You can't echo an object you have to serialize it in a way that vue can understand.